# How to create ROS subscriber which will remember the last message until the new one?

Tags: python

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.
I use python.
I want to use the loop based on data of Publisher.
For example, If I get the data == 1, I need to print "Hello" every 3 seconds, until when I will receive the new message with another data.
Please help me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242918/how-to-create-ros-subscriber-which-will-remember-the-last-message-until-the-new-one?/) by [Tvlad](https://answers.ros.org/users/27335/tvlad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2016-09-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Subscriber callbacks run on their own thread, so I usually update a variable in the subscriber callback and then use that data in a main loop running in the startup thread. Something like this:

```
import rospy

class MyNode:
    def main(self):
        rospy.subscriber('sometopic', SomeMsgType, self.msgCallback)
        self.value = None
        self.rate = rospy.getParam('~rate', 10.0)
        while not rospy.is_shutdown():
            ... do something with self.value ...
            rate.sleep()
    
    def msgCallback(self, newValue):
        self.value = newValue

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        MyNode().main()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

---

Originally posted by [Mark Rose](https://answers.ros.org/users/27558/mark-rose/) with karma: 1563 on 2016-09-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tvlad](https://answers.ros.org/users/27335/tvlad/) on 2016-09-05**:
Thank you, but I have a question. For what we use the line:

```
self.value = None
```

And, Can I use the loop like this:

```
while self.value == "data":
```

Sorry If it's the stupid questions.

**Comment by [Mark Rose](https://answers.ros.org/users/27558/mark-rose/) on 2016-09-06**:
You have to set a value for `self.value` before the `while` loop runs. Python will throw an exception if you try to access an attribute that doesn't exist. I just chose `None` so you can determine that no value has been received yet. I'm not sure if I understand your loop question.

**Comment by [Mark Rose](https://answers.ros.org/users/27558/mark-rose/) on 2016-09-06**:
The main loop must be `while not rospy.is_shutdown()` so that you will exit if the ROS core shuts down. You'll probably want to check for `None` within the loop:

```
if self.value is not None:
    ... do something ...
```

**Comment by [Mark Rose](https://answers.ros.org/users/27558/mark-rose/) on 2016-09-06**:
You should read the `rospy` tutorials. Start with [the first one](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy_tutorials/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber).